# How can I configure the following CMake project?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, googletest

- [Configuration of CLion + CMake + GoogleTest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYt4Sh-ocGU)

In the above video, the author uses the following directory structure:

[image]

1. The project's name is `unit-testing`
2. The `unit-testing` directory has three subdirectories `lib`, `src`, `tst`
3. The `lib` directory has a subdirectory `googletest` where the google unit testing framework resides.
4. The `src` directory keeps the header and source files
5. The `tst` directory keeps the test *.cpp files
6. `unit-testing`, `src`, and `tst` each has one `CMakeLists.txt` files

The content of `unit-testing/CMakeLists.txt` is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(unit_testing_01_gtest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(src)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tst)
add_subdirectory(lib/googletest)
```

The content of `unit-testing/src/CMakeLists.txt` is as follows:

```
set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cpp)

set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})

add_executable(${BINARY}_run {SOURCES})
add_library(${BINARY}_lib STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

The content of `unit-testing/tst/CMakeLists.txt` is as follows:

```
set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_test)

file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES false *.h *.cpp)

set(SOURCES ${TEST_SOURCES})

add_executable(${BINARY} ${TEST_SOURCES})
add_test(NAME ${BINARY} COMMAND ${BINARY})

target_link_libraries(${BINARY} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_lib gtest)
```

I want to do some modifications:

1. The `src` directory will contain *.hpp files
2. The `tst` directory will contain *.cpp files
3. There will be only one `main.cpp` file in th entire project and that would be located in the top-most directory `unit-testing`

**What modifications should I make in `CMakeLists.txt` files and why?**

**Which `CMakeLists.txt` should I delete?**

---

I deleted the `src/CMakeLists.txt`

I modified the `tst/CMakeLists.txt` as follows:

```
set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_test)

file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES false *.cpp)

set(SOURCES ${TEST_SOURCES})

add_executable(${BINARY} ${TEST_SOURCES})
add_test(NAME ${BINARY} COMMAND ${BINARY})

target_link_libraries(${BINARY} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_lib gtest)
```

I modified the `unit-testing/CMakeLists.txt` as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(unit_testing_01_gtest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(src)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tst)
add_subdirectory(lib/googletest)

add_executable(unit_testing main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(unit_testing unit_testing_lib gtest)
```

Now, I am getting the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CMake Error at C:\git\MatrixMultiplicationProjectCpp\CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    C:/git/MatrixMultiplicationProjectCpp/src

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.   unit_testing_01_gtest   C:\git\MatrixMultiplicationProjectCpp\CMakeLists.txt    9
```